# Occasional text printing - inkjet or laser?

Tags: printer

Is it worth buying a inkjet printer if all I do is text printing, of say, 100 pages per year and that too irregularly? I heard that the inkjets get clogged up if not used regularly. So, should I go for laser printers (which cost 2x here) or stay with inkjets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent years with one inkjet after another dying on me. Finally I got a laser printer and it was the best decision I ever made - and cheaper in the long run when you factor in the cost of ink and the cost of occasionally replacing the entire printer when it clogs up.

Comment: Is the running costs of laser cheaper? I mean, is there any problems similar to clogging inks etc when using laser printers?

Comment: @abc3489weq: As far as I am aware, laser printers don't clog even when left unused for ages and the ink is cheaper on a per-page basis.

Comment: Is there anything at all to keep in mind before buying laser printers?

Comment: Check out the speed to print first page from cold as well as the speed of subsequent pages. Check the price of the cartridges. Be aware that there may be cartridges that look the same size but contain different quantities of ink.

Comment: There is kind of a "hidden" cost with laser printers, as well as the toner, there is also the drum and fuser, these two don't get replaced as often as the toner, but some can be very expensive. Some printers have the drum integrated into the toner cartridge so that makes the toner more expensive, but you won't have to worry about replacing the drum. I think the fuser is always a separate part.

Comment: My black-and-white laser printer (HP P1505) got me over 1500 pages (AND COUNTING!) with the stock cartridge.  The printer only cost me $60 at the time, so currently it's costing me $0.04 per page :D

Comment: It's worthwhile to check around for used laser printers. They often have much useful life left.

Answer (score 1):

Running costs of printers are usually far higher than the purchase price. At home I have a small laser printer used for occasional printing of the sort of volume you are discussing. I have had it about six years and it is still on the original toner cartridge.  For a shorter period of time I have owned an inkjet based copier/fax machine that gets used a bit more regularly and has had to have cartridges replaced a few times. On this basis I would recommend a small laser.

I wouldn't rely too much on anecdotal evidence though.

Comment: So, am I correct in saying that for my printing needs, I just need to buy a laser printer now and not worry about any problems occurring to it? Even if I just leave it unused for 2 months straight? Or is there a catch somewhere? (apart from the initial costs)

Comment: Leaving it unused for two months should not be a problem. I've not encountered any unexpected catch.